# Undefined method `contacts_path' in Rails with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm trying to add a contact form to my spree-based site. Here's the error I have currently:

```
Showing /Users/louisstephancruz/loosecanon/app/views/spree/contacts/new.html.erb where     line #7 raised:

undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe8a4703de0>:0x007fe8a4702670>
```

Here's the relevant view file (new.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
<h1>Contact</h1>

<div align="center">
  <h3>Send Us a Message</h3>

  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    <div class= "hidden">
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      </br>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

contacts_controller.rb:

```
module Spree
  class ContactsController < Spree::HomeController

    def new
      @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
      @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
      @contact.request = request
      if @contact.deliver
        flash.now[:error] = nil
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my routes, I've got:

```
match '/contacts', to: 'spree/contacts#new', via: 'get', :as => :contacts
resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'simple_form'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.0.6'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'spree', '2.2.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_fancy', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_fancy.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_digital', :git => 'git://github.com/halo/spree_digital.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_blogging_spree', github: 'stefansenk/spree-blogging-spree'
gem 'spree_editor', github: 'spree/spree_editor', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_related_products', github: 'spree/spree_related_products', branch: '2-2-stable'
```

I've tried moving the controller/view files out of the spree folder, and I've also tried a dozen things in the routes file. What am I missing here?

**Edit**

Rake routes (the relevant stuff):

```
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern             Controller#Action
      spree      /                       Spree::Core::Engine
   ckeditor      /ckeditor               Ckeditor::Engine
      about GET  /about(.:format)        spree/static_pages#about
   contacts GET  /contacts(.:format)     spree/contacts#new
            POST /contacts(.:format)     contacts#create
new_contact GET  /contacts/new(.:format) contacts#new
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` say about it?  Is it listed?

Comment: Also, just in case, have you re-started your `rails s` instance if that's what you're using?  I've had new routes not get picked up and cause confusion.

Comment: Have you tried `namespace :spree do resources :contacts end`?

Comment: Nick, I'll post rake routes above, and yes, I have restarted the rails server with every change.

Comment: Iceman, I haven't given that a shot. Where exactly would I put that?

Comment: Instead of `resources :users` in routes.rb

Comment: @Iceman, that didn't solve the problem, but now I do get the error "Unable to autoload constant ContactsController, expected /Users/louisstephancruz/loosecanon/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb to define it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your doing this on the store side, you have to do, routes:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
    resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Your version of Spree maybe different from mine, you get the general idea though.

Then on your form you can do:

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, :url => contacts_url :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

try these variations if above doesnt't work: `:url => spree_contacts_url`

```
:url => spree.contacts_url
```

play around with the url and look at rake routes, it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything. Thanks again though!

Comment: could you edit post to include output from rake routes?

Comment: made a few edits, I think it should solve your issue.

Comment: Hm, no good yet. I tried all of those combinations without luck.

Comment: Oh, now I see! It worked when I put "Spree::Core::Engine.routes.append do..." in my application routes. I didn't even have to point the :url. Thanks @railsdevmtl! (I'll be sure to up vote you when I have enough reputation.)

Comment: Glad you figured it out!